# Multiple Table Update On (Hands On Table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

[image: fig1]

I am using Handsone table on three seperate instances of tables.

[image: Fig 2]

I declare them as you can see here.

[image: Fig3]

When I try to save them, I get the data from each of the tables.

[image]

To my surprise, it consolidates the all of the tables.

[image]
In the first picture I only filled the settlement Table.

I would be expecting that only the handsontable('getData') should only take the data that is on that table. Not all of the data in all of the handsontable in the page. There must be a cause of why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing your handsontables, you are using restArg for 3 of your instances. Are they using the same datasource?

You may want to have a read about "[Understanding binding as reference](http://handsontable.com/demo/understanding_reference.html)":

```
http://handsontable.com/demo/understanding_reference.html
```